# Simple Sinatra routing Json file

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

I'm writting a simple Sinatra Api that returns a Json file for an specific URL.

this is the code for the server.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
set :public_folder, 'public'
get '/' do
    'Hello world!'
end

get '/api/spells' do
    content_type :json
    File.read('public/spells.json')
end
```

However, I kept receiving this error of no such file. Please help! Thank you!

```
 Errno::ENOENT at /api/spells
 No such file or directory - /spells.json
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message shows, it's a problem with your path. According to [documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__static_files_directory), by default, the `File.read('public/spells.json')` will try to find `spells.json` file in a folder named `public/`, make sure you put the json file there.

Answer (score 1):

How are you running the application? If you're using this over rackup or thin, they will not serve files from `public/`.

You also do not need to set

:public_folder, 'public'

if the folder `public/` exists, it will automatically attempt to serve files from that folder. You only need to set that option if you are using a folder that is not `public/`.